# How to save electronic equipment from ants?

Tags: safety, security, hdd

Today I brought out my external HDD and it was full of red ants. It took me an hour to remove the ants (it seems quite impossible to remove all of them; some are still inside). I always see some ants are coming out of my laptop. My sister's laptop is infested too. Some keys are not working. So, it's a big problem. I have two questions:

- Does anyone know how to prevent red ants from entering electronic equipment like laptop, HDD etc?
- How to remove the ant colony that are inside the laptop, HDD?

*I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, but I don't see any other option.*

Comment: Ants **LOVE** EM radiation.

Comment: Burn everything to the ground and start over?

Comment: Have you tried ANTacid?

Comment: Oh, wait, I get this... What you're looking for is an ANTidote.

Comment: Did you try certain condiments such as pepper or cinnamon? some types of ants don't like them..

Comment: You need an in-circuit debugger.

Comment: 1. Search for a cockroach. 2. kill it. 3. put it beside the HDD. 4. Wait for ants to move from the HDD to the cockroach and you're done!

Comment: Hire an aardvark.

Comment: Your question is about insects infesting things in your home, not about electronics design. By coincidence, they've found a home inside electronic equipment, but it could just as well be your furniture or food supplies. I would recommend asking on diy.stackexchange.com as I believe home pest control is on-topic there. See http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=ants

Comment: "Cream of Tarter" may reduce their travel. "Torro" ant killer, they will take to their nest and kill the colony. They have a daily supply of water, remove it. Place the HDD in a ziploc bag when not on use.

Comment: The documentary film Phase IV has some pointers. The MST3K version is considered definitive.